# Error when import from GitHub

Tags: solidity

Why when I'm trying to import from github it show error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While importing directly from GitHub might be helpful within the Remix editor, it's better to install packages when working in Visual Studio Code. In your console:

```
npm init  
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

Then, you can change your line to:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```